# PHP Misplace DocType warning

Tags: php, domdocument

I am getting an error for php `domdocument` in run time saying

```
error: "DOMDocument::loadHTML() [<a href='domdocument.loadhtml'>domdocument.loadhtml</a>]: Misplaced DOCTYPE declaration in Entity, DOMDocument::loadHTML() 
line: 1 DOMDocument::loadHTML() [<a href='domdocument.loadhtml'>domdocument.loadhtml</a>]: htmlParseStartTag: misplaced &lt;html&gt; tag in Entity, line2:
```

My codes

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();

@$doc->loadHTML($htmlString);
```

My html string could be varies.

I am not sure how to solve this issue. Can anyone suggest a solution? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you should make every effort to try to ensure proper markup. However, you can suppress these errors with:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
```

Which will not trigger errors due to malformed HTML (but you can still access them using `libxml_get_errors` if you want to see the issues encountered during parsing.